# NodeMCU tmr - bad argument #1 to 'alarm' (boolean expected)

Tags: lua, mqtt, nodemcu

I have a function called after wifi is connected to setup my mqtt connection. But for some reason it panics when my reconnect timer should be setup.

The arguments to `alarm` are correct ?!

```lua
local setupMqtt = function()

  m = mqtt.Client("esp1", 10)

  local mqtt_connect = function()
    m:connect("192.168.43.110", 1883, false)
  end

  local handle_failure = function()
    tmr.create():alarm(2500, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, mqtt_connect)
  end

  m:lwt("/lwt", "offline", 0, 0)

  m:on("connect", function(client)
    print("connected")
    m:publish("/lwt", "online", 0, 1)
  end)

  m:on("connfail", function(client, reason)
    print("failure", reason)
    handle_failure()
  end)

  m:on("offline", function(client)
    print("offline")
    handle_failure()
  end)

  mqtt_connect()

end
```

I am using the 3.0.0.0 dev branch because there are bugs with mqtt in the master branch

```
NodeMCU 3.0.0.0 
        branch: dev
        commit: b4c148eff07c9aaeeb29a89fbf838f78960fe655
        release: 3.0-master_20200610 +23
        release DTS: 202008301904
        SSL: false
        build type: float
        LFS: 0x0 bytes total capacity
        modules: adc,bit,dht,file,gpio,http,i2c,mdns,mqtt,net,node,ow,tmr,uart,wifi
 build 2020-09-04 09:25 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 3.0.1-dev(fce080e)
```

This is working

```
local M = {}

function M.setup()

  local m = mqtt.Client("esp1", 10)

  local mqtt_connect = function()
    print("connect")
    m:connect("192.168.1.100", 1883, false)
  end

  local t = tmr.create()
  t:register(10000, tmr.ALARM_SEMI, mqtt_connect)

  m:lwt("/lwt", "offline", 0, 0)

  m:on("connect", function(client)
    print("connected")
    m:publish("/lwt", "online", 0, 1)
  end)

  m:on("connfail", function(client, reason)
    print("failure", reason)
    t:start()
  end)

  m:on("offline", function(client)
    print("offline")
    t:start()
  end)

  mqtt_connect()

end

return M
```

Comment: the first argument `2500` of the `alarm` method are expecting for a value of type boolean (like true or false), and you are passing a value of type integer

Comment: @WardyGuardian while that statement is true based on the error OP is getting, their use of alarm seems to match the documentation https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/tmr/#tobjalarm

Comment: @Pascal do you get the same error if you use `:register` and `:start` rather then `:alarm`? Also what revision are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug that will be fixed with PR [#3263](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/3263). We will merge it in the next hours or days.